# Why are browsers not displaying HttpOnly flag?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, session-cookies, cookie-httponly

> ASP.NET session cookies are HTTP only, regardless of the
>   httpOnlyCookies setting linked to in your question, because this is
>   burned into ASP.NET. You can't override this.

Source: Accepted answer at [How is HttpOnly get set for ASP.NET_SessionId cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247143/how-is-httponly-get-set-for-asp-net-sessionid-cookie)

I am unable to see that flag in browser when response is received. Application web.config does not have httpCookies element defined nor is HttpOnly property set to false in Global file.

[image]

However, in the pen test report, it talks about using unsecure asp.net session cookie, I can see the HttpOnly flag for the same request. See below:

[image]

Again, I am not asking about cookie security or pen test issue itself. I am just wondering why browser is not showing flag. Tried in IE and Chrome both.

Comment: Oooo.. not a single comment!