# Delete ASP.SessionId cookie from within Selenium IDE

Tags: asp.net, selenium, firefox, cookies, ide

I have seen many posts about this and there are some conflicting messages or statements that I can't verify myself.  I am using selenium IDE and I am trying to "Expire" or "Delete" the ASP.SessionId within the browser.

1. It is stated that you cannot delete the ASP.SessionId cookie because it is set by the server as detailed (Http only).  This I can't verify.  I have opened up Charles, Fiddler and Visual Studio webtests and I only see the cookie as "HTTP" and not "HTTP only".  That is the first issue.
2. I see the cookie being set and passed back and forth in the requests in Fiddler and visual Studio but when Selenium IDE tries to grab the cookie to a variable I define, Selenium IDE says it is not found.  This is the second issue.
3. When I run the command "DeleteAllVisibileCookies" it is successful (step is marked green in the IDE), but there is no change to the cookies as they still exist.

Does Selenium IDE have the ability to see browser cookies (if so, what are the caveats) and manage them?

Note:  I am able to capture the AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport cookie and view/set it successfully.  Not sure what the difference is with the ASP.SessionId cookie.

Comment: Interestingly when I run the command "DeleteAllVisibleCookies" it passes with GREEN in the IDE.  I think today for the first time this command turned RED and the error was "Cannot find cookie ; Language".  I would assume that every other time it is deleting the ASPsessionID because of no error about finding it.  However, when I run fiddler, I do in fact have the same ASPsessionID cookie value.

Comment: I now know it is not possible to modify a session cookie (i.e. ASP.NET_SessionId) as it is HTTP only (can only be modified by the server).  the question that I have now is why can't Selenium IDE at just view/read the cookie with storeCookieByName?

Comment: Here is the StackOverflow article detailing the session cookie rules (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247143/how-is-httponly-get-set-for-asp-net-sessionid-cookie/2247221#2247221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (ASPsessionID) cookie is not able to be set/controlled by Selenium IDE and is only controlled by the server.  This cookie is specified as "HTTP" only and that prohibits Selenium IDE from making changes to that cookie.