# Sitecore with requireSSL for cookies

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, requiressl

Our Sitecore 6.6.0 (rev. 120918) based website can work over http as well as https. We also have a security requirement of making all the cookies to transfer over SSL regardless of whether the website is accessed via http.

We have achieved this requirement by using the requireSSL property in the web.config as described here: [How can I set the Secure flag on an ASP.NET Session Cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442863/how-can-i-set-the-secure-flag-on-an-asp-net-session-cookie)

With this change, our public website works fine and when analyzed in Firebug, we can see that all cookies are "secure" even when the website is accessed via http.

But the problem is when I try to login to the sitecore admin portal via http, it throws the error `The application is configured to issue secure cookies. These cookies require the browser to issue the request over SSL (https protocol). However, the current request is not over SSL.` The only way I can access the sitecore admin portal is via https. Even with https, it gives some weird issues. After some time of use, it says that lot of admin users are logged in and I have to kick some out to get in. I also can't access the admin portal remotely.

Why is it that the public website works with SSL cookies, but the sitecore admin portal has issues with SSL cookies. Could it be and incompatible configuration in our site?

Comment: I have the exact same problem with our Sitecore 6.2.0 environment. It works fine in our dev & test environment where there is no F5. But in our load balanced environment I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem will be that you have set `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />` which will set the cookies to secure, but also have to set the forms authentication:

```
<system.web>
    <forms requireSSL="true">
        /* forms content */
    </forms>
</system.web>
```

As this would override the cookie setting. The problem is having that set on the forms section requires that the login happen over https not http. On your public website, you will only see this issue if there is a login form.

To fix this you will either have to enable SSL for your authoring system (which is recommended anyway) or put up with not using secure cookies.

[MSDN: FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.requiressl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The problem is sitecore seems to be causing issues even when it's fully accessed via https. I still didn't do an analysis on these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message I'd guess the login is trying to set a cookie with the secure attribute when the connection isn't secure. This would of course succeed if the request was secure already.

As a workaround you may be able to use IIS Rewrite to redirect the request to /sitecore onto SSL prior to any cookies being set since I assume you do want all requests on SSL for content management.

I might also be totally incorrect here :)

Comment: The secure attribute for cookies should not depend on whether the site is accessed via http or https. In fact, the secure flag for cookies ensures that cookies are always transferred via ssl even when the site is accessed via http.