# Session variable to authenticate users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, session-variables

What should I do if someone tries to access page which is only allowed after being logged in to users. I have done this but it doesn't work, please help:

```
public ActionResult ViewMyAtdRecord()
{
    int EmplID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Employee"]);

    if (Session["Employee"] == "")
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "NOT AUTHORIZED TO VIEW THIS PAGE";
        return View();
    }
    else 
    {
        IEnumerable<GetAtdRecord_SpResult> MyAtdRecord = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(EmplID).ToList();
        var names = (from n in DataContext.HrEmployees select n).Distinct();
        return View(MyAtdRecord);
    }
}
```

Actually session begins here.

```
public ActionResult AfterLogIn(int EmplID, String EmpPwd) 
{
    int Num_Rows = (int)DataContext.GetUser_Pwd(EmplID, EmpPwd).First().No_Rows;
    if (Num_Rows == 1) 
    {
         Session["Employee"] = EmplID.ToString() ;
         ViewBag.Message = Session["Employee"];
    }
    else
    {
         ViewBag.Message = "Log-in Failed";
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: any help would be great sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `FormsAuthentication` (as suggested by @akton) and decorate the actions/controller with the [Authorize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute

If you want to go with `Session` rather than `FormsAuthentication` then you could try this out :

```
public ActionResult ViewMyAtdRecord()
{
    int empId = 0; 
    int.TryParse((string)Session["Employee"], out empId); // parse variable to int

    if (empId > 0) // we have an employee id, lets show that record.
    {
        IEnumerable<GetAtdRecord_SpResult> MyAtdRecord = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(empId ).ToList();
        var names = (from n in DataContext.HrEmployees select n).Distinct();
        return View(MyAtdRecord);
    }
    else // we do not have an employee id, show not authorized message.
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "NOT AUTHORIZED TO VIEW THIS PAGE";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: EmplID doesn't exist in currect context, ERROR

Comment: @Evilrising - I took the liberty to change the variable name, since local variables should start with a lower case letter. Replace `empId` with `EmplID`; and I had a typo.

Comment: Int.Try parse has some invalid arguments

Comment: Done, Used OUT before ermplid

Comment: @Evilrising - Indeed, I forgot that one.

Answer (score 4):

First, avoid using session for storing authentication evidence. It makes you vulnerable to [session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) - someone can easily copy and reuse the contents of the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie, particularly if the site is accessible over HTTP and not HTTPS.

Use authentication cookies instead. Yes, cookies have some disadvantages, such as giving malicious users the ciphertext of your authentication cookie. However the [FormsAuthenticationProvider](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443) has been developed with this in mind. This is why it is generally [considered safer to use cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068961/asp-net-mvc-4-and-session-security-leak).

Second, try to avoid using session at all. One of the huge advantages of [ASP.MVC is the ability to run sessionless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181629/why-session-is-a-disaster-in-asp-net-mvc-application), allowing you to easily scale up your site if needed.