# How to change sessionid after login in .NET?

Tags: .net, security, session

For security reasons, I want to change session_id after login. In php, there's a function `session_regenerate_id();` which can change `sessionid` without losing current session information.

Is there a similar function in .NET ?

Comment: A good idea is to change the session ID, however you should also use Forms Authentication Tickets rather than session for authentication (if not already ;)) [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18077422/413180).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET does not directly support functionality to regenerate a session ID. See the documentation regarding the issue. There is a [not-so quick and dirty way](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899918) to do it by setting the ASPNET_SessionID value to the empty string and redirecting so that the value is regenerated.