# Is there a direct way to test the Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie

Tags: testing, ssl, cookies, attributes, internet-explorer-11

Is there a direct way to test the value of the Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie, for example, by using IE 11?  I need to ensure that the Secure Attribute is set to "True"....

NOTE:  I programmed the answer to How can I set the Secure flag on an ASP.NET Session Cookie? in the web.config of my ASP.net-MVC project.  The answer can be found here:

[How can I set the Secure flag on an ASP.NET Session Cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442863/how-can-i-set-the-secure-flag-on-an-asp-net-session-cookie)

However, I want to know how to directly test the result (i.e. in IE -- always wanted to say that!) without just relying on the web.config being correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Using the method described in How can I set the Secure flag on an ASP.NET Session Cookie? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442863/how-can-i-set-the-secure-flag-on-an-asp-net-session-cookie does indeed work; but I still don't know how to directly verify this.  Someone else used a scanning tool to determine that it did work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the `Set-Cookie` header in the HTTP response in Fiddler or your dev tools' network atb, and make sure it includes the `Secure` flag.