# Secure flag not set to Cookies in .Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, session-cookies

I have included below lines of code in my Web.Config and Global.asax.cs file. Still when I use developer tools in browser I could see secure flag not set to the below Cookies.

Also Configured SSLSettings in my IIS(Selected checkbox requireSSL).

I would like to set Secure attribute to all Cookies not only to received but also to Sent cookies. Any suggestion please.

In Web.config:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true"/>
```

In Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.IsSecureConnection == true && HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme == "https")
    {
        Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionID"].Secure = true;
        if (Request.Cookies.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string s in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
            {
                Request.Cookies[s].Secure = true;
            }
        }

        Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionID"].Secure = true;
        if (Response.Cookies.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string s in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
            {
                Response.Cookies[s].Secure = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Browser:[image]

Comment: Try the same code in Application_BeginRequest or in Session_Start.

Comment: @G01 - I have used the code in Global.asax.cs file as you suggested. But same result. Any other way to set secure?

Comment: Set HttpOnlyCookie to true in Web.config file.

Comment: @G01 - No luck.

Comment: In Web.config file, check for lockItem or lockattribute. If so, remove and check it again in browser.

Comment: @G01 - I tried bot the options. Added and removed lockitem in HttpCookie but no luck. Still same result.

Comment: Please refer below URL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442863/how-can-i-set-the-secure-flag-on-an-asp-net-session-cookie

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, one httpCookies element in web.config allows you to turn on requireSSL which only transmit all cookies including session in SSL only and also inside forms authentication, but if you turn on SSL on httpcookies you must also turn it on inside forms configuration too.

```
<form>
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```